# Make smooth texture libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures

I have some texture buttons with filter `MipMapLinearNearest`, nearest for aspect ratio 16:9, and everything looks fine even on different devices.

*But on aspect ratio 8:5 buttons becomes not smooth.*

I use FitViewport with virtual size 1280:720.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that this is only hapened for resolutions lower than 1280:720.

Maybe reason is my filter 'MipMapLinearNearest', 'Nearest'?

Comment: are you sure that you are using Fitviewport properly? Do black bars appear when they need to?

Comment: yes, i have black bars on screen

Comment: You probably want to carefully read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, but it's not solve my problem